# Apply format to null string

Tags: format, character, sas

I'd like to apply a label to nulls in a character variable.

I can do this quite fine with numeric variables, but am unsuccessful with character vars. I'd like to apply the label 'Both Groups' to the null Group value (as created by the `class` option in `proc means`).

```
data group1;                      
   input group $1. freq;  
   datalines;
A 5
B 8
  13
;
proc format;
    value $ grpfmt  'A' = 'Group A'
                    'B' = 'Group B'
                    ''  = 'Both Groups'
                    ;
run;
proc sql;
    create table group2 as
        select group format = $grpfmt.,freq
            from group1;
quit;
```

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add space to the value of Both Groups, like

```
' ' = 'Both Groups'
```

Another way is to use the other option in the proc format.

```
other = 'Both Groups'
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a wild guess...

did you try NULL = 'Both Groups' ?